# Image pop up codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

(I'm using codeigniter framework)
I have a table in my webpage which contains 3 fields id, name and img(path).

```
<table>
<?php foreach($record->result() as $row)
{?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->id?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->name?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->img?></td>
    <td><button>Click me</button></td>

}?>
</table>
```

This works fine, everything is getting displayed. Now what i want is when i press the 'Click me' button the img of that particular row should pop up. I have no idea how to do this. Pls help ;)

Comment: you want to show pop up image in bootstrap modal??

Answer (score 1):

Try this one mate : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Replace the image with buttons if you wanted.
Use Bootstrap to make your buttons making easier.